# Vanilla JS or React for making NPM packages? Which is better?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, package

I have few ideas for my npm packages but I need a little bit of help as I am just starting out. I saw tutorials on youtube and they all write those packages in vanilla JavaScript and I saw few repos on GitHub where the package was made in react.

**My goal** is to make special components that people can just put in their app and render out and later customize through passing down props. For example:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player

This React Player - which you basically put in your app and pass down props to customize

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player/youtube'

<ReactPlayer 
    url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U' 
    playing='true'
    controls='true'
/>
```

**Should I make my project in React or vanilla JS in my case? What are the benefits of whatever I choose?**

I am a little confused because everyone on YouTube is teaching making it in vanilla JS.

Thank you a lot for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you want your code consumed like ‘ReactVideoPlayer’ using ‘props’, you are talking about building a reusable React component. For this you by definition need to use React.

You would use Vanilla JS for building a library that could be used in any JavaScript context, in or outside of React.